# UIButton Touch Events Outside NavigationBar

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationbar

I have two buttons placed near the bottom of the screen.  I also have a transparent UINavigationBar.  I want to dock those two buttons at the top of the view when the user scrolls the content.  I have made two attempts at this, but both fail me.

1)  I've placed the two buttons inside a UIView and set that UIView to the titleView of the nav bar.  This makes them buttons non-responsive while they are "outside" the bounds of the nav bar.

2) I've added the two buttons into the main view above all of the other content.  This causes the buttons to be non-responsive when scrolled up, as they are "behind" the nav bar.

If I could somehow allow the buttons to be placed inside the nav bar, yet still be responsive when down near the bottom of the view, i'd be good to go.  Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Currently testing in iOS 7 & 8.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think you need the nav bar at all, since you could just use a new view for the upper two buttons?

Comment: @DylanGattey - Good thought man.  I considered that, but I lose all of the functionality of the UINavigationBar such as state management and some built-in animation control.  I suppose I can live without these things if this turns out to be impossible, but it just seems like there should be a way to do this.

Comment: I totally agree. But I think Apple's too restrictive to allow us to do that. Sucks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add two invisible button on your navBar with same action, but process those actions only when your non-invisible buttons are near with navBar.

Other way, you can keep bottom buttons on same place, when you scroll view.
Or put them directly on navBar and don`t scroll at all.

I hope you can find better solution.

Comment: This would work, and I appreciate the ingenuity, but I'm hoping to not actually settle on a work-around.

My current (work-around) solution is having a set of buttons in corresponding positions in the nav and I'm toggling the visibility of this set versus the set on the main view.

Similar to your approach, but still not as elegant as a solution as being able to capture touch events on a single set of buttons from the navigation bar, IMO.

Comment: ending up going this route, as there doesn't seem to be a way to make views touch-able outside the nav bar :(